# Cordova inAppBrowser plugin issue on windows

Tags: node.js, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

so I've been trying to add this plugin with command

> cordova plugin add
>   https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git

which worked on MAC and Linux after

> npm update -g cordova

but on windows I'm still getting

> cannot read property 'install' of undefined

Moreover - when I'm trying to uninstall ( `cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser` ) then I'm getting

> cannot read property 'uninstall' of undefined

Weird thing is that I have two cordova folders - one in
`C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules` and the second one in
`C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules` . Path which I added to my environmental variables is `C:\Users\mati\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\.bin`

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is the problem reported about a week ago as [CB-6008](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6008) on the Cordova bug tracker.

It may be a symptom of having an out-of-date cordova installation still. The issue there was solved by removing and reinstalling Cordova to ensure that the latest version was in use.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the content of your platforms and plugins folder. re-install your plugins and the problem should be gone. In my case the following command

phonegap local plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser

produced -> [error] Cannot read property 'install' of undefined

and the above procedure fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a platform to your cordova project (before trying to add a plugin)?

npm update -g cordova 
cordova create myproject
cd myproject
cordova platform add android
cordova plugin add **_**

I think the undefined error means a dependency of the add plugin command is not there.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was to update plugman module:

`npm install -g plugman`